# Migrating domain to sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, server, react-js

I have a WordPress hosted on WPMUdev that lives under `example.com`, and trying to move this WordPress installation to `sub.example.com` and set my react app on `example.com`.

So I tried to move my website from `example.com` to `sub.example.com` so my WordPress can live in `sub.example.com` and my react app in `example.com`. WordPress is hosted on WPMU dev and React app on Vercel.

I've been able to set my React app on `example.com` in Vercel dashboard after setting up my DNS record accordingly ( DNS records are set up in my domain name provider ) but I'm struggling to set my WordPress on `sub.example.com`.

I've tried to set a CNAME records with `sub.example.com` and A record with IPv4 WPMU servers IP but this does not work.
Domain name provider says I just need a CNAME record for subdomain but this also does not work.
On domain panels in WPMUDEV I've added `sub.example.com` but it always fails on DNS Check. I also tried a few combinations of A/CNAME records but also fails.
What am I missing?

Comment: When you say "fails on DNS Check," what does that mean?  What checks is it performing?  What is the full error message you get?

Comment: thanks for your reply. @StephenOstermiller

under the DNS Status column I have a red cross and when I hover on it it just says " Wrong DNS.Please check our DNS docs and review your setup.It can take 24-48 hours for DNS to fully propagate in some cases."

Also I don't know what checks it does, WPMU UI does not say, and you can't really do much

Comment: The weird parts is that when I access on my browser `sub.example.com` it does not work but somehow my React app which communicate with WordPress via Rest API do work with `sub.example.com`

Comment: Okay I made some progress, 
I've added a CNAME record with a URL provided by WPMU Dev (domain.tempurl.host) and now the DNS Check on WPMU Dashboard I successful and I'm able to set `sub.example.com` as my primary URL, but when I hit this URL in my browser it redirects me to `example.com` (react app ) instead of my WordPress

Comment: Did you update the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL variables in your WordPress config?

Comment: No I did not, since my wp-config.php did not had these in the first place. I'm trying

Comment: I've added these two on my wp-config.php but it did not changed anything

Comment: `wp-config.php` is the right place to set them.  See https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: Is there any way to see how your host has configured your virtual server config?  Does it tell you what document root directories the domain and subdomain point to?

Comment: I suspected the change in wp-config.php did not work so I've took a look in the database and manually changed `siteurl` and `home` from `domain.com` to `sub.domain.com`, still did not changed anything, i'm still redirected to domain.com in browser. And unfortunately I can't find anywhere in WPMUdev UI anything related to virtual server

Comment: Also in the WPMUDev overview there is a line CNAME with domain.tempurl.host, and when I enter this in my browser it points to sub.domain.com but with a 404 from Vercel...

Answer (score 1):

turns out you were right, with the correct site_url and only the CNAME from WPMUDev it works, thanks for your help